# Nginx proxy_set_header doesnt added to header of POST request

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

It's my first time when I set up nginx.
For one proxy server I have to add authorization and
it works, but just for "GET" method, on "post" request there are no authorization header.
I also have post request to this proxy server.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name xxxxxxxxx;
        return 301 xxxxxxxxx;
       }
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name {$server_name};

        location /path {
            proxy_set_header Host xxxxxxxxx;
            proxy_pass xxxxx;
            proxy_set_header Access_Control_Allow_Headers "Authorization";
            proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic xxxxxxxxxx";
            proxy_pass_header Authorization;
            proxy_pass_header Access_Control_Allow_Headers;
        }
      }
```

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work", what exactly happens?

Comment: @Brad The header authorization appears on Get Method(I added to logs the list of header in backend) But on Post requests it doesnt come with header